# Unix terminal - How to print every bigram/trigram of a line?

Tags: text-processing, grep

How can I print every bigram of a line using the unix terminal? Punctuation symbols are considered as a 'word'.

For example, if I have to following input:

```
This is ! line .

This is ! second line .
```

My output should be the following, if searching for every bigram:

```
This is
is !
! line
line .

This is
is !
! second
second line
line .
```

My output should be the following, if searching for every trigam:

```
This is !
is ! line
! line .

this is !
is ! second
! second line
second line .
```

The command

```
grep -Eio '[a-z!.]+ [a-z!.]+'
```

Returns

```
This is
! line
This is
! second
line .
```

Which comes close, but is not yet what I need.

Comment: Maybe you could ask this to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ !

Comment: Sorry for the reject, but I can't see any osx-specific thingy here.

Answer (score 5):

You can use perl like so

bigram

```
perl -lne 'while(/(\S+\s+\S*){1}/){print $&;s/\S+\s+//}' file

This is
is !
! line
line .
This is
is !
! second
second line
line .
```

trigram

```
perl -lne 'while(/(\S+\s+\S*){2}/){print $&;s/\S+\s+//}' file

This is !
is ! line
! line .
This is !
is ! second
! second line
second line .
```

Change number in the curly brackets for however many you want per line (-1).

Comment: good one.. here's a regex only version for fun.. haven't tested extensively.. `perl -lpe 's/(\S+\s+)(?=(\S+(\s+\S+){0})\s+)/$1$2\n/g'` where the number in `{}` is `x-2`

Answer (score 4):

You'd need a `grep` implementation that is not only able to print portions of the lines (like your grep with its `-o` option to print only what is matched as opposed to the line where there's a match) but also portions of the lines *several times*.

`pcregrep` is one of them:

```
pcregrep -o1 -o2 --om-separator=' ' '(\S+)\s*(?=(\S+))'
```

Here, `-o2` prints something that is not matched per se, something that is only matched in a *look ahead* operator (`(?=...)`), so `pcregrep` will resume looking for more matches starting from the end of the word output by `-o1`.

`\s` matches spacing (vertical or horizontal) characters, so *words* in that case are sequences of non-spacing characters.

Instead, you could use `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) print $i, $(i+1)}'
```

For `awk`, *words* are sequences of non-blank (horizontal spacing) characters, in some implementations limited to SPC and TAB.

If you wanted to consider `line.` as two separate *words*: `line` and `.`, you could use the GNU implementation of `awk` that supports defining fields based on patterns like:

```
gawk -v FPAT='[[:alnum:]]+|[[:punct:]]+' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) print $i, $(i+1)}'
```

Where *words* are defined as either sequences of alphanumerical characters or sequences of punctuation characters.

Comment: In Mac terminal, using this command returns: -bash: pcregrep: command not found. This is part of a class exercise, so we can not use external libraries. Sorry, I'm, just starting to learn all those commands!

Comment: The awk command worked perfectly fine! Thank you a lot! Unfortunately I can not upvote yet.

Comment: @ThijmenDam these are two good solutions that satisfy what you told us. If you don't bother to mention that you have to have this run on a Mac, or that the requirements are constrained because it's homework, we won't know. Incidentally, although asking for an answer to your homework is permitted *here*, it won't help you learn.

Comment: I know. It's not that I just want it to work. It is important that I understand what it does. However, this command is the last one that's necessary for a bigger 'problem'. I got the other commands right, it is just this one last step which I could net get my head around.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I do not yet completely understand your command, but I'll sort that out the next lesson :-)  Could you adjust it, so it also works for trigrams? Edit: Tried this:  awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)}'. However this also returns some bigrams.

Comment: @ThijmenDam, you'd need to loop from the first to the (NF-2)th field.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Wouldn't it be `NF-1`th ?

Comment: @123, you'd need `i` to go up to `NF-2`, so `i <= NF-2` or `i < NF-1` instead of `i < NF`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Sorry, this use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), not [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

for *bigram*:

```
sed 'h;:a;s/^ *\([^ ]\+\) \+\([^ ]\+\).*$/\1 \2/p;g;s/^ *[^ ]\+//;h;ta;'
```

or maybe (replacing `\+` by `\{1,\}` as [Stéphane Chazelas's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/733859?noredirect=1) pointed out:

```
sed -e 'h;:a' -e 's/^ *\([^ ]\{1,\}\) \{1,\}\([^ ]\{1,\}\).*$/\1 \2/p;g;s/^ *[^ ]\{1,\}//;h;ta'
```

and for *trigram*:

```
sed 'h;:a;s/^ *\([^ ]\+\) \+\([^ ]\+\) \+\([^ ]\+\).*$/\1 \2 \3/p;g;s/^ *[^ ]\+//;h;ta;'
```

For Mac's `sed`:

```
sed -e 'h;:a' -e 's/^ *\([^ ]\{1,\}\) \{1,\}\([^ ]\{1,\}\) \{1,\}\([^ ]\{1,\}\).*$/\1 \2 \3/p;g;s/^ *[^ ]\{1,\}//;h;ta'
```

#### Explained:

*Bigram* as a sed script:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

    h;                                       # Hold pattern space to hold space
:a;                                          # label for branch
    s/^ *\([^ ]\+\) \+\([^ ]\+\).*$/\1 \2/p; # print 1st bigram
    g;                                       # restore from hold space
    s/^ *[^ ]\+//;                           # drop 1st monogram
    h;                                       # hold pattern space
    ta;                                      # branch if last search success
```

where last `t` (conditional branch) to label `:a` only if last `s///` did match.

#### And the *Mac's `sed`* version of bigram.sed:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f

    h;                                    # Hold pattern space to hold space
                                          # label for branch
:a
    s/^ *\([^ ]\{1,\}\) \{1,\}\([^ ]\{1,\}\).*$/\1 \2/p; # print 1st bigram
    g;                                    # restore from hold space
    s/^ *[^ ]\{1,\}//;                    # drop 1st monogram
    h;                                    # hold pattern space
                                          # branch if last search success
    ta
```

Comment: This returns the following output: 

This is ! line .

This is ! second line .

Comment: Note that `\+` is a GNUism. The POSIX equivalent is `\{1,\}`

Comment: The `:`, `t` and `b` commands cannot be followed by other commands on the same line. With many implementations, `ta;` jumps to the `a;` label (and `ta; # ...` to the `; # ...` label).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas There is no command after the only `t` at end of my script.

Comment: @ThijmenDam Maybe you could try second sample, where `\+` is replaced by `\{1,\}`!

Comment: @ThijmenDam Answer tested under Mac OS!